# %include% component hides other elements on web page

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I am building a web app that has an interactive map of venues in my hometown. The app is written in Django and the map itself is built using Folium, then is saved as `map.html` and rendered in a template as follows:

```
{% extends "venues/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% include 'venues/map.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The layout.html file simply has a bootstrap navbar:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" id="navbar-default">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">CultureMapMilano</a>
        <div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link"
                        href=""><strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
                </li>
                {% else %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                </li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    
    <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
```

**The issue**. When I click on the map the navbar simply disappears. It's still there in the DOM but it's behind the map.
I assume it's a problem I could fix with css but I don't know how to (adding a high z-index to the navbar didn't help).
Interestingly putting the %include% inside a  means the map just doesn't show - no idea why.

Can someone suggest a way to fix this or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: just add a `height` property set to e.g. 90% when generating the Folium map.